# How can I access one particular section of a grouped tableview?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, height, landscape, footer

I would access a particular section of a grouped uitableview for changing its footer height in landscape mode.

If I use

```
self.tableView.sectionFooterHeight = 75.0;
```

in

```
-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

the footer height of all sections is changed, but I want a changing only in the first sections's footer height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must do that in

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

When you do the rotation do an reloadData on the tableView and in the  `heightForFooterInSection` test for the particular section and for the `UIDeviceOrientation`

Good luck

Edit:

You get the device orientation

```
UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
```

Comment: Great! I used -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section, but I forgot the reloadData. The result isn't yet perfect, but at least I figured out what it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

and maintain an array of all footer height's as instance variable.